# What happened to the Acre OAuth Console?

Tags: facebook, oauth, freebase, freebase-acre

following official [freebase facebook app tutorial](http://facebook-app.tutorials.freebaseapps.com/tutorial), in **Step 4** it mentions the *Acre OAuth Console* but attempting to access the url provided in the tutorial (inserting your app name and your user id where indicated)

> `http://<your app name>.<your user id>.user.dev.freebaseapps.com/acre/oauth`

results in the error:

> No Such file **acre** in app

Where did the OAuth Console go?

Comment: You should probably ask whoever that runs the Acre site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OAuth console is now part of the application settings dialog which you can get to by clicking on the name of your app at the top left of the Acre IDE. Then, go to the Web Services tab and you can add OAuth keys as usual.

[image]

This feature is  useful for any APIs that need to use a key to make API requests. All Acre apps are open source so you don't want to put those keys in the source code.

Comment: note for future users skimming the console: if you aren't connected over https you will see the following message instead: `For your security, please switch to App Editor over SSL to add or edit your API keys.` At time of writing, this text is not highlighted, bolded, or remarkable in any way & is easy to miss.